# Is it possible to have Entity Framework use List<T> instead of ICollection<T> when generating classes from the DB?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco

Title is pretty self explanatory. I would like to have my EF autogenerated partial classes to use List intead of ICollection.

Comment: Which Template are you using to generate the classes? We're using Self Tracking Entities and the navigation properties are `TrackableCollection<T>`, which derives from `ObservableCollection<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. I have done so many times. Are you having some problems generating it?

Ex: `public virtual List<Property> Properties { get; set; }`

Comment: Agreed
However I would advise you to use TrackableCollection instead of List, if you at all intend to use WPF at all.

Comment: Hi... I'm new on this and I'm having the same issue with Icollection... I need to change it for another collection type. I see the edmx properties, but i can't find where to change the collection type... or where to get another template... I'll appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

No because when you hit .ToList() which will return a List EF will hit the database with the query so it's always better to cal .ToList at the end